# mvn test on multi module project?

Tags: maven

I have a strange issue and I don't know if my conclusion is correct. I have a multi module project with two children:

```
Rector build order:
mvn-project-test
mvn-project-core
```

core depends on test (so the build order is correct). Of course, running 'mvn test' doesn't install any artifacts locally. When running it, maven complaints (correctly) that ~/.m2/respositories/...../mvn-project-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar is missing and the core build fails.

Shouldn't maven use the dependencies from the target folder of other multimodule children? Or must I always use 'mvn test install' on multi module projects? (Or third, I'm completely wrong and my whole project configurationis somehow broken)

Finally, the test project hasn't any content, yet, just dependencies so the jar is empty. But that shouldn't be a problem, right?

Cheers,

Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were ideas for Maven 3 to allow the various mojos to see the whole build and do magic like "if none of my upstream projects changed, skip my tests" and things like that.

But as it is, each module is independent. Dependencies will only be resolved from the local repository. So if you don't `mvn install`, your tests won't work.